# Reuse of conditions (when) in Drool DSL statements

Tags: drools, dsl

Is it possible to reuse a when/condition statement into another when/condition statement in a DSL file?

For example, I have two conditions:

```
[condition][]The client is invalid = Client( name == null || email == null )
[condition][]All the clients are invalid = forall( Client( name == null || email == null ) )
```

Note that the second condition just diff the first for the *forall* command, but the statement inside is equals. In these case, I want to reuse the first condition into the second.

Is it possible? How?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

even the most recent version of drools will only let you substitute values into a template from pojo's or a corresponding map as per their documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR3/drools-expert-docs/html/ch02.html#d0e1972).

This won't work for your use case though.

Since drool files are simply text files, there is nothing preventing you from considering a more powerful templating toolkit.

Possibilities include [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/), [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) or [Scala](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates)!